# How many Mapreduce Jobs can be run simultaneously

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know How many Mapreduce Jobs can be submit/run simultaneously in a single node hadoop envirnment.Is there any limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a configuration standpoint, there's no limit I'm aware of. You can set the number of map and reduce slots to whatever you want. Practically, though, each slot has to spin up a JVM capable of running some hadoop code, which requires some amount of memory, so eventually you would run out of memory on your machine. You might also have to configure job queues cleverly in order to run a ton at the same time.

Now, what is possible is a very different question than what is a good idea...

Comment: memory is one thing, but won't multiple mapreduce jobs scheduled on the same node compete for the cpu as well? Would we see great performance benefit to running jobs serially?

Answer (score 1):

You can submit as many jobs you want, they will be queued up and scheduler will run them based on FIFO(by default) and available resources.The number of jobs being executed by hadoop will depend as described by John above.

Answer (score 0):

The number of Reducer slots is set when the cluster is configured. This will limit the number of MapReduce jobs based on the number of Reducers each job requests. Mappers are generally more limited by number of DataNodes and # of processors per node.